# No provider for Http while HttpModule is imported

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a project that come from an angular 4 bootstrap 4 template.

I got the famous `Error: No provider for Http` while using a custom service that need it to do request to a custom API :

```
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {Config} from "../../../webapp/src/config";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";

/**
 * Created by Sorikairo on 4/24/2017.
 */

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    public isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
    public token: string = null;

    constructor(public http: Http, public config: Config) {

    }

    public loginUser(user) {
        return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl + "login/user", {user: user}).map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    public createUser(user) {
        return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl + "user", {user: user}).map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    public createProduct(product)
    {
        return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl + "product", {product: product}).map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    public modifyProduct(product)
    {
        return this.http.put(this.config.apiUrl + "product", {product: product}).map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }



    public extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }

    public handleError(error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        return Observable.throw(error.json());
    }

    public IsLoggedIn() {
        return this.isLoggedIn;
    }

    public setToken(token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public setStatus(status) {
        this.isLoggedIn = status;
    }
}
```

However, HttpModule is imported in my app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { MaterialModule} from '@angular/material';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { NgbModalModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { TourNgBootstrapModule } from 'ngx-tour-ng-bootstrap';
import { NgxDatatableModule } from "@swimlane/ngx-datatable";


import { PerfectScrollbarModule, PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from "ngx-perfect-scrollbar";
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateStaticLoader } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import { SidebarModule } from 'ng-sidebar';
import 'hammerjs';

import { ChankyaAppComponent} from './app.component';
import { AppRoutes } from "./app-routing.module";
import { MainComponent }   from './main/main.component';
import { HorizontalLayoutComponent } from './horizontal-layout/horizontal-layout.component';
import { MenuToggleModule } from './core/menu/menu-toggle.module';
import { MenuItems } from './core/menu/menu-items/menu-items';
import { PageTitleService } from './core/page-title/page-title.service';
import {LoginoneComponent} from "./login/loginone.component";
import {FilterTableComponent} from "./table/table-filter.component";
import {DashboardRoutes} from "./dashboard/dashboard.routing";
import {DirectivesModule} from "./core/directive/directives.module";
import {NgxChartsModule} from "@swimlane/ngx-charts";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {DashboardComponent} from "./dashboard/dashboard-v1/dashboard.component";
import {UserListComponent} from "./user-pages/user-list/userlist.component";
import {ProductListComponent} from "./product-pages/product-list/productlist.component";
import {CompanyListComponent} from "./company-pages/product-list/companylist.component";
import {ProductDetailComponent} from "./product-pages/product-detail/productdetail.component";
import {RouterOutletComponent} from "./router-outlet.component";
import {ApiService} from "../../../webapp/src/app/api.service";

export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json');
}

const perfectScrollbarConfig: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
  suppressScrollX: true
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HttpModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MaterialModule,
        SidebarModule.forRoot(),
        RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
        TourNgBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
        FlexLayoutModule,
        NgbModalModule.forRoot(),
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({apiKey: 'AIzaSyBtdO5k6CRntAMJCF-H5uZjTCoSGX95cdk'}),
        PerfectScrollbarModule.forRoot(perfectScrollbarConfig),
        MenuToggleModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        NgxChartsModule,
        DirectivesModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(DashboardRoutes),
        NgxDatatableModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [Http]
        }),
    ],
    declarations: [
        ChankyaAppComponent,
        MainComponent,
        LoginoneComponent,
        HorizontalLayoutComponent,
        FilterTableComponent,
        DashboardComponent,
        UserListComponent,
        ProductListComponent,
        CompanyListComponent,
        ProductDetailComponent,
        RouterOutletComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [
    ],
    bootstrap: [ChankyaAppComponent],
    providers:[
        MenuItems,
        PageTitleService,
        ApiService
    ]
})
export class ChankyaAppModule { }
```

My dependencies are up-to-date or at least support NgModule:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "5.3.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "9.3.0",
    "angular-calendar": "0.19.0",
    "angular-resizable-element": "^1.2.0",
    "angular-sortablejs": "^2.0.6",
    "angular-tree-component": "3.8.0",
    "chart.js": "2.6.0",
    "ckeditor": "4.6.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.9.1",
    "dragula": "3.7.2",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.7",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "intl": "^1.2.4",
    "jquery": "2.2.4",
    "jqvmap": "^1.5.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.0.2",
    "leaflet-map": "0.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.15.0",
    "ng-sidebar": "^6.0.0",
    "ng2-ace-editor": "^0.2.3",
    "ng2-archwizard": "^1.7.0",
    "ng2-breadcrumb": "0.5.14",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "1.1.9",
    "ng2-dnd": "^4.2.0",
    "ng2-drag-drop": "^2.5.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "1.5.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.2.1",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^3.0.1",
    "ng2-translate": "5.0.0",
    "ng2-tree": "^2.0.0-alpha.10",
    "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
    "ng2modules-easypiechart": "^0.0.4",
    "ngx-mydatepicker": "2.0.12",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^1.3.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^5.3.0",
    "ngx-tour-ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.6",
    "normalize.css": "^5.0.0",
    "nvd3": "^1.8.5",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^0.6.16",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.5",
    "quill": "^1.2.3",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "tether": "1.4.0",
    "screenfull": "^3.2.2",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "skycons": "^1.0.0",
    "sortablejs": "^1.6.0",
    "summernote": "^0.8.4",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "widgster": "0.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.2",
    "@types/d3": "^3.5.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.52",
    "@types/jquery": "3.2.0",
    "@types/node": "7.0.8",
    "@types/nvd3": "^1.8.33",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.3",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.6",
    "tslint": "5.4.3",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  }
}
```

I have other project created with angular cli that do not fail to provide Http, only this one has a problem, but I cannot find why...

Comment: Can you show us your AppModule ? Or any Module involved in your custom service. Please :)

Comment: @NoémiSalaün Edited. Couldn't do it in first place due to code/text ratio when creating a question :)

Comment: Try to put `BrowserModule` first in your dependencies.

Comment: @edkeveked same result. I think it's probably a dependence which is breaking it, ng-cookie did it on earlier version for example. Can't find which one tho'

Comment: Indeed, whether it is caused by one of `npm` dependencies or it is because of the services you are injecting in your `providers`

Comment: @edkeveked Ok I fixed, it. I was importing the ApiService from another angular 4 part of the project named webapp (from another directory with its own dependencies and version). Moved into this part fixed the error. But now, I have duplicated code.

Comment: I will make it as an answer and you can accept it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157622/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-sorikairo).

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be coming whether from one of the `npm` dependencies or from the services you are injecting in your `providers`.

You can try to see if there is no circular dependency in your services or if there is a service you are not injecting in you `providers`.